# Delete all rows except latest per user, having a certain column value

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-delete

I've got a table `events` that contains events for users, for example:

```
PK | user | event_type | timestamp
--------------------------------
1  | ab   | DTV        | 1
2  | ab   | DTV        | 2
3  | ab   | CPVR       | 3
4  | cd   | DTV        | 1
5  | cd   | DTV        | 2
6  | cd   | DTV        | 3
```

What I want to do is keep only one event per `user`, namely the one with the latest `timestamp`  and `event_type = 'DTV'`.

After applying the delete to the example above, the table should look like this:

```
PK | user | event_type | timestamp
--------------------------------
2  | ab   | DTV        | 2
6  | cd   | DTV        | 3
```

Can any one of you come up with something that accomplishes this task?

Update: I'm using Sqlite. This is what I have so far:

```
delete from events
where id not in (
  select id from (
    select id, user, max(timestamp)
    from events
    where event_type = 'DTV'
    group by user)
);
```

I'm pretty sure this can be improved upon. Any ideas?

Comment: We are terrible in helping those who cant help themselves or who dont try.

Comment: What is your database system?

Comment: What have you tried? How close have you managed to come to a solution? Please update your question with that information.

Comment: Is `timestamp` unique per `user`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
delete from events
where (user, timestamp) not in (
    select user, max(timestamp)
    from events
    where event_type = 'DTV'
    group by user
)
```

You could potentially do some more sophisticated tricks like table or partition replacement, depending on the database you're working with

Comment: I'm using Sqlite and I'm getting a syntax error near the comma in `(user, timestamp)`. I'll update my question with some adjustments to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If using sql server roo5/2008 then use following sql:

```
;WITH ce 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY [user], event_type 
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rownumber 
         FROM   emp) 
DELETE FROM ce 
WHERE  rownumber <> 1 
        OR event_type <> 'DTV'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't seem to me reliable enough, because your subquery is pulling a column that is neither aggregated nor added to `GROUP BY`. I mean, I am not an experienced SQLite user and your solution did work [when I tested it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cb6ce/6). And if there's any confirmation that the `id` column is always reliably correlated to the `MAX(timestamp)` value in this situation, fine, your approach seems quite a decent one.

But if you are as unsure about your solution as I am, you could try the following:

```
DELETE FROM events
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS ts
    FROM events e
    WHERE event_type = 'DTV'
      AND user = events.user
  ) s
  WHERE ts = events.timestamp
);
```

The inner instance of `events` is assigned a different alias so that the `events` alias could be used to unambiguously reference the outer instance of the table (the one the `DELETE` command is actually being applied to). This solution does assume that `timestamp` is unique per `user`, though.

A working example can be run and played with [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cb6ce/2).

Comment: Timestamps **should** be unique per user, but some querying shows that there are indeed some duplicates. With this delete, I end up with more events than distinct users (`select count(0) from events` is greater than `select count(distinct user) from events`), whereas I obviously expect each user to have at most one last 'DTV' event. Could this be a direct result of timestamps not being unique for a user?

Comment: @Bossie: Yes, I'm afraid uniqueness of time stamps per user is crucial for this solution.